# Do I need to parse the complete json using moshi on Android?

Tags: android, json, retrofit, moshi

If there is a Rest-API where I get a very large JSON but I only need a few fields of it, for example only the first block in it, do I need to manually create kotlin data classes for ALL the fields in the JSON to be able to parse work with json data? What's the current best practice of handling such a case?

Comment: Moshi will parse the complete JSON text but it will skip past fields you have not modeled in Kotlin (unless you enable `failOnUnknown()`). Omit fields as much as you like. Or parse json as `Map<String, Object>` and you will get a map where the keys are the json field names and the objects are strings, maps, or lists depending on the json data type

Comment: @zapl I see, I will try that out, I think you can post that as solution. Btw. what if I need to model the whole JSON, is there a generator special for Android, I tried and one and the generated code uses deprecated code and also duplicates classes, so not sure what to do.